# Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::__construct() must implement interface

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.8

I have read other questions about my error so I re-checked my code and didn't found any typo mistake , 
Error

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError
>   (E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR)     Argument 2 passed to
>   Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::__construct() must implement interface
>   Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider, null given, called in
>   \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager.php on line
>   125

Auth.php

```
return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admin',
        ],

        'user' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'user',
        ],

        'company' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'company',
        ],

        'employee' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'employee',
        ],
    ],



    'providers' => [

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],

        'company' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Model\Employee::class,
        ],

        'employee' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Model\Employee::class,
        ],

    ],

];
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @morph read 2nd para of question which I am getting error for multiple authentication.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::\_\_construct()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57888578/laravel-argument-2-passed-to-illuminate-auth-sessionguard-construct)

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the provider for your new guard otherwise it will throw the error. Your provider should also be spelt **'admins'** as you are referencing the particular migration table for **admins**

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],


    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything was fine I was just called old default user auth in controller which I was modified in old project and now I am installed new project and then move all of files except user.php default model

```
 $companyAuth = auth()->guard('user'); //called wrong default 
 $companyAuth = auth()->guard('employee'); //now working fine
```