# Laravel 8 : Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider, null given

Tags: php, laravel-8, laravel-authentication

I am trying to create multiple guard authentication for Users and Admins for my application. Before you mark it as duplicate or something, please read it and let someone help me. I have tried all the possible solutions from same issues solutions but nothing worked till now.

Here is my code:

auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'providers' => 'admins'
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],

    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\AdminUser::class,
    ],
],
```

AdminUser.php

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class AdminUser extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;
    protected $table = 'admin_users';

    protected $guard = 'admin';

    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name',
        'middle_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];


    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];


    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

AdminAuthController.php

```
class AdminAuthController extends Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:admin');
    }

    public function getLogin()
    {
        return view('login');
    } 
}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/login', 'LoginController@index')->name('login');
Route::get('/admin/login','AdminAuthController@getLogin');
```

When I go to **my-application/login** it ask for username and password and let me in once authenticated. But when I go to **my-application/admin/login**, it gives me this error:

> Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider, null given, called in /var/www/vhosts/my-application/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php on line 124

I tried solutions with the same issue, but nothing helped.Laravel documentation is bit confusing and so I am here to seek your help. Please help me out and I appreciate your help in advance. I am using Laravel 8.*

Comment: I can't speck to your specific error, but have a question instead: why do `User`s and `AdminUser`s need to be different Models? I'd recommend going with a single `User` model and `Role`s for `normal` and `admin`. This way, you wouldn't have to mess with the providers, and a simple middleware to check that the `User` has the right `Role` would handle this.

Comment: I appreciate your idea, but that's how the schema was made and that's how we want to move forward.

Comment: No worries! I know it's been done, but it's a bit of an anti-pattern (i.e. many of the columns in the `users` tables would be the same as in the `admin_users` table, like `name`, `email`, `password`, etc., goes against DRY). I'd take a look and see if there are any packages for Authentication for Laravel that operate in this way, and see if you can mimic how they've handled it. Best of luck!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::\_\_construct()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57888578/laravel-argument-2-passed-to-illuminate-auth-sessionguard-construct)

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue just yesterday. I am relatively new to web development. It turned out the issue arose from my cofig/auth.php. In setting the "guards" section, I set the provider to reference the table name ('provider' => 'admins_user') rather than the "providers" section below it ('provider' => 'admins').
**Solution:** When I pointed guards to the "providers" section, it was resolved. I know it's a silly mistake on my side but I hope this helps someone out there with similar circumstances.